# How to add a Karma plugin to an Angular 16 that has no karma.conf.js

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I have an Angular projects which I created using the v16 CLI. All the unit tests locally fine using `ng test`.

I now wanted to set these up to run on out build machine that runs teamcity. In previous Angular projects (which I did not setup), they all have a `karma.conf.js`, and also  a `src/test.ts` which has the comment

> // This file is required by karma.conf.js and loads recursively all the .spec and framework files

In previous projects I have installed `karma-teamcity-reporter`, and then in the `karma.confi.js` I add  `require('karma-teamcity-reporter')` to the plugins array, and we can then run this from team city using `ng test --watch=false --browsers=ChromeHeadless --reporters=teamcity`

However, when I went to do the same for my newer project, there is no `karma.conf.js`,or `src/test.ts`. If I search for another line like `require('karma-jasmine')` I find it no where.

I am not sure if in the older project someone (no longer here) added and setup the `karma.conf.js` themselves, but my question is how do I now add this `karma-teamcity-reporter` to my Angular project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### UPDATE

Create the Karma configuration using `ng generate config karma` and/or edit your `angular.json` adding `"karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js"` under the `test > options` section and `"builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma"` under the `test` section.

Example of `test` section in `angular.json`:

```json
{
  // ... more stuff
  "projects": {
    "project_ name": {
      // ... stuff
      "architect": {
        // ... stuff
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

##### OLD ANSWER:

You need to install the official CLI and then initialize the config file with `init`:

```bash
$ npm install -g karma-cli
$ karma init my.conf.js
```

Reference: http://karma-runner.github.io/6.4/intro/installation.html and http://karma-runner.github.io/6.4/intro/configuration.html

Comment: I did the above, and this gave me the `karma.conf.js` (thats hat name I gave it). I then added `plugins: [require('karma-teamcity-reporter')]` (and some others as per other Angular projects), however on Teamcity, it still reports `26 10 2023 17:01:58.343:ERROR [reporter]: Can not load reporter "teamcity", it is not registered!`

Comment: Have you ran `npm install karma-teamcity-reporter`?

Comment: Try to totally remove the "plugins" configuration. In this case, Karma will look for packages in `node_modules` that start with `karma-`

Comment: @Albero -  Yes I has installed `karma-teamcity-reporter` and I have it's folder in `node_modules`. I tried removing the plugins sections, but still the same error from TC `30 10 2023 07:03:54.209:ERROR [reporter]: Can not load reporter "teamcity", it is not registered!` Perhaps Angular (when running `ng test`) is just not looking at this config?

Comment: @peterc i've updated my answer (again)

Comment: thankyou, this now works! The missing bit for me was the `"karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js"` in the `angular.json`, After adding this, it now works on TC.